# Не работает загрузка файла Yii2

Tags: yii2

Делаю загрузку фото в редактировании профиля. Для поля загрузки поля прописал

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput(); ?>
```

Когда отправляю форму, делаю вывод того, что передается

```
print_r(Yii::$app->request->post());
```

и получаю это

```
Array ( [_csrf] => SzZPazVRNHUbRx80fSFXAAEBGz1mB1gNOG96HVwVWTBmQX8denx.Ig== [EditProfile] => Array ( [username] => zaych [email] => mail@site.ru [first_name] => Admin [second_name] => Admin [image] => ) [signup-button] => )
```

То есть, поле image пустое, хотя фото выбираю.
Для формы прописал

```
'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Потому что файлов нет в посте - они в переменной $_FILES в PHP. Или `UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');` - в yii2 .

Comment: я делаю так `$file->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($file, 'image'); print_r($file->image);` и пусто

Comment: есть у кого то еще мысли?